# 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type in Object' in *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to display the following object:

```
export const articles = {
  hardware: ['CPU', 'Motherboard', 'GPU', 'RAM', 'Power Supply'],
  Software: ['Operating System', 'Program', 'Web Site'],
  compsci: ['Algorithm', 'Programming', 'Data Structure']
}
```

Like this:

```
<h2>Browse through our articles:</h2>
<section *ngFor="let key of keys">
  {{key}}
  <div *ngIf="myArticles.hasOwnProperty(key)">
    <span *ngFor="let arr of myArticles[key]"><app-list-detail [list]="arr"></app-list-detail></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Where **arr** gets sent to a child component as **list**. But I get the error in the title. I thought it was because TS had no way to know if **key** was an actual property of **myArticles**, so I added the ***ngIf** above.

But it still doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `keyvalue` pipe to iterate on objects:

```
<h2>Browse through our articles:</h2>
<section *ngFor="let entry of articles | keyvalue">
  {{entry.key}}
  <span *ngFor="let arr of entry.value"><app-list-detail [list]="arr"></app-list-detail></span>
</section>
```

Comment: Had to modifiy the **<span>** such that it takes an element from **entry.value** (which is an array) and just displays it, therefore eleminating the need for the **<app-list-detail>** component.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the error you would need to specify type for `articles`. You can specify type as:

```ts
    export const articles: Record<string, string[]> = {
      hardware: ['CPU', 'Motherboard', 'GPU', 'RAM', 'Power Supply'],
      Software: ['Operating System', 'Program', 'Web Site'],
      compsci: ['Algorithm', 'Programming', 'Data Structure']
    }
```